# Looping in R with dynamic variables as dataframe names

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to loop through dataframes where my search variable is in the name of the dataframe. Here I have multiple dataframes beginning with "person", "place", or "thing" and ending with either "5" or "8." I would like to loop through the many combinations of beginning and ending to create a temporary dataframe. The temporary dataframe will be used to create a plot and save the plot.

When I try my current code, I'm able to get the variable name to loop correctly (in other words, I can get "person_odds5" or "place_odds5"), but I cannot use those variables to access the corresponding column in the dataframe.

My current code is:

```
person_odds5 <- data.frame(odds=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), or_lci95=1:4, or_uci95=11:14, id.exposure=c("f", "g", "h", "i"), id.outcome=c("w", "x", "y", "z"))
place_odds5 <- data.frame(odds=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), or_lci95=5:8, or_uci95=15:18, id.exposure=c("f", "g", "h", "i"), id.outcome=c("w", "x", "y", "z"))
thing_odds5 <- data.frame(odds=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), or_lci95=9:12, or_uci95=19:22, id.exposure=c("f", "g", "h", "i"), id.outcome=c("w", "x", "y", "z"))
nouns <- list("person", "place", "thing")
for (x in nouns) {
    pval <- c(5)
    for (p in pval) {
        name <- paste(x,"_odds",p, sep="")
        odds <- paste(name,"$odds", sep="")
        temp_dat <- data.frame(odds=odds, index=1:nrow(name))
    }
}
```

When I run this code, my output for "name" is "person_odds5" as character type; my output for "odds" is "person_odds5$odds" as character type, and I encounter "Error in 1:nrow(name) : argument of length 0." Basically, it appears that I can't parse my name assignment through the original dataframe.

Input:

```
>person_odds5
  odds or_lci95 or_uci95 id.exposure id.outcome
1    a        1       11           f          w
2    b        2       12           g          x
3    c        3       13           h          y
4    d        4       14           i          z
>
```

Desired output:

```
>temp_dat
 odds index
1    a     1
2    b     2
3    c     3
4    d     4
>
```

Comment: You can use `odds <- get(name)$odds"`

Comment: Thanks to you both! The get(name)$odds answer worked.